# How to pass a value/variable from an android java class to javascript/.html file in android 4.4.2 kitkat

Tags: java, javascript, android

I need to pass a **value/variable (e.g. integer, string)** from my **java class** to the **.html file** inside android assets. Let's say it is an integer value based on the user's click. I need to pass **this** integer to the .html file(scripts) so as to determine which ajax call is to be made (via an if-else loop). I googled everywhere but I couldn't find an answer to this.

I need to achieve this on android 4.4.2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html? You are interested in **Binding JavaScript code to Android code** section. First declare interface, then implement the method that will return your integer. Then inside your `JS` code call this method to get the value.

**EDIT**

Interface for working with JS:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Get the value */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public int getValue() {
        return value
    }
}
```

Add this interface to your `WebView`:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

Inside your JS code:

```
var value = Android.getValue();
```

Comment: I have read that. Can you provide me with a simple way/code snippet which can pass the integer value from java class (onClick method) to .html file(scripts)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know why I got stuck in this simple thing, but your help is appreciated.

Comment: Can we directly use HTML file instead of your answer for JS? I want to use a button to create HTML file and writes the variables directly inside of the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Your Mainactivity.java may go like this

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    StringGetter stringGetter;
    String key;
    WebView webView;
    String url;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // Here The key value might be an integer or string 
      // I have used string

      key="sending values to javascript";


         url = "file:///android_asset/Index.html";
        webView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());



        stringGetter = new StringGetter(this);

        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new StringGetter(this), "AndroidFunction");



    }

    public class StringGetter {
        Context jContext;

        StringGetter(Context context){
            jContext = context;
        }
        @JavascriptInterface
        public String getString() {
            return key;

        }
    }



    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }




    }


}
}
```

Your HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function myMethod(){

        var tct = AndroidFunction.getString();
        document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = tct;
        alert(tct);
        }



    </script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

    <input type="button" id="btn" value=" Check " onClick="myMethod()"/>



    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Some Name </a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href = "#">Downloads</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        Dropdown
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div></li>
                </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">ColUMN 1 contains some text and other components to work with </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">COLUMN 2 contains some text and other components to work with </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">ColUMN 3 contains some text and other components to work with </div>
        <p id="p">hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```