# Backspace key does not delete Thai vowels on webview's Html text input

Tags: android, webview, backspace, thai

I am using Android Studio 2.1.1.

I open a local html file with an input of type text in my webview. I found that the backspace key of the dynamic keyboard does not delete any of the Thai vowels which are either over or under a consonant letter. However, on the EditText view, the backspace key does not have any issue with the Thai vowels. It deletes all characters, both the Thai consonants and vowels.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText);
    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test_input.html");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.thongjoon.edittext.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@id/simpleText"
    android:text="Hello World!"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/simpleEditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/simpleText"
    android:hint="Enter Your Name Here" />
<WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
         android:layout_below="@id/simpleEditText"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

test_input.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="th">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Document</title>
   </head>
<body>
  ทดสอบ<input type="text" name="yourname" value="Your Name"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to Android. I really don't know how to go about this problem. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I decided not to use html input of type text. In stead, I created a JavaScriptInterface class to pass a variable to a javascript function. The variable is from an EditText view. I pass it on a button click.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.thongjoon.edittext.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@id/simpleText"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/simpleEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/simpleText"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:hint="Enter Text Here" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/simpleEditText"
        android:text="Go"/>

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
         android:layout_below="@+id/btnSearch"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="150dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

test_input.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="th">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>

  ทดสอบการส่งตัวแปรจาก Android<br>
  Passing a variable from Android to Javascript<br>

  <script>
    function init(val){
      alert(val);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

JavaScriptInterface.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public static String getFromAndroid(String myVar) {
        return myVar;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String inputText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // hide virtual keyboard. Show keyboard when user touches EditText view
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
        );

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText);
        final Button btn_search =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

        final WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //for showing Javascript alert box
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test_input.html");

        btn_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //hide virtual keyboard
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                       inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            inputText = simpleEditText.getText().toString();
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:init('" + inputText + "')");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Many thanks to the following links;

[Passing data from java class to Web View html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752052/passing-data-from-java-class-to-web-view-html)

[Get Value of a Edit Text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field)
[How to pass a value/variable from an android java class to javascript/.html file in android 4.4.2 kitkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222265/how-to-pass-a-value-variable-from-an-android-java-class-to-javascript-html-file)

[Passing data from java class to Web View html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752052/passing-data-from-java-class-to-web-view-html)